# Visualizing the complex exponential (with complex inputs)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function

I recently learned that if you move along a horizontal line in the complex plane, the outputs from $\sin$/$\cos$ along that line trace an ellipse, with foci at $-1$ and $1$.  As you move the line up or down, the ellipse gets exponentially bigger/smaller.

[image: sin/cos diagrams]
*Diagram from Needham's "Complex Visual Analysis"*

This really helped me understand how complex $\sin$/$\cos$ behave.  However, I'm missing that deep understanding for $e^{iz}$.

**How does $e^{iz}$ behave for various horizontal *(or vertical?)* input lines?**

Or, if this is not an enlightening question, **what's a better way to visualize how $e^{iz}$ behaves as you move the input around the complex plane?**

Comment: It is much easier.  $e^{iz} = e^{ix} e^{-y}$ turns horizontal lines to circles around the origin, and vertical lines to rays emanating from the origin.

Comment: The first thing you want to do is understand, thoroughly,  what $e^z$ does to horizontal and vertical lines.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: Well that was stupidly easy.  If you write an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much easier than sin/cos. $e^{iz}=e^{ix}e^{−y}$ turns horizontal lines to circles around the origin, and vertical lines to rays emanating from the origin.